# Graph API hook to Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating a Microsoft graph webhook so an Azure Function triggers when a new email arrives to my Inbox.

My setup is:

- dotnet Azure Function with an MSGraph "Outlook message webhook creator"

[image: Outlook messagewebhook creator]

- A MultiTenant Microsoft App so my Azure Active Directory can ask for
  permissions `Mail.Read`

The problem is: after accepting the requested permissions, Graph returns "Invalid request" `Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.`

I also tried to create the subscription manually via the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) but the error is consistent
[image: Error Graph Explorer]

Comment: I too have a similar issue. my notification url is azure function and I don't receive the validationToken in azure function to validate.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the `notificationUrl` in your request body is invalid.

The subscription notification endpoint (specified in the `notificationUrl` property) must be capable of responding to a validation request as described in [Set up notifications for changes in user data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation). If validation fails, the request to create the subscription returns a 400 Bad Request error.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
   "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}
```

See reference - [**Notification endpoint validation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#notification-endpoint-validation).

Comment: If my Azure Function's type is "Outlook message webhook creator", shouldn't Azure take care of what you are saying --The subscription notification endpoint must be capable of responding to a validation request-- That's the point of "extensions" of the Azure Functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#webhooks

Comment: @gantonioid The function is used to create the subscription, it will not create the webhook notification client, if your notificationUrl is invalid, where do you want to the notification send to? So could you make sure your `notificationUrl` is valid?

Comment: @JoyWang my notification url is azure function and I too get an similar error. I'm not receiving the validationToken to validate the request.